# datatype/md5sum error

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I've been trying to run [link text](https://github.com/ethz-asl/waypoint_navigator) and i constantly get this error:

```
[ERROR] [1575375869.500571590]: Client [/firefly/trajectory_sampler] wants topic /firefly/path_segments to have datatype/md5sum [mav_planning_msgs/PolynomialTrajectory/2daf5d705534e84f80980f4673a0e62b], but our version has [mav_planning_msgs/PolynomialTrajectory4D/4d68d15524ede489eecd674bb6dc3ee8]. Dropping connection.
```

I was told that i may need another version of mav_comm folder ( [link text](https://github.com/ethz-asl/mav_comm) ) but no matter what i try i get the same error.
Can anyone tell me how to fix that??

Thank you!

I use ubuntu 16.04 and ROS kinetic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339058/datatype/md5sum-error/) by [alice-st](https://answers.ros.org/users/49955/alice-st/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-12-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jungx148](https://answers.ros.org/users/50882/jungx148/) on 2020-01-13**:
Having the exact same problem (and same environmental setup).
Is there guidance which we could follow to compile with the same version of the mav_planning_msgs package?

Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to make sure you've compiled both pieces of software with the same version of the `mav_planning_msgs` package.

Something has changed in that message between versions so they don't line up. More than just that, it looks like you're using the *wrong* message type.

```
mav_planning_msgs/PolynomialTrajectory != mav_planning_msgs/PolynomialTrajectory4D
```

You've subscribed to a topic with a specified type that is not the type the topic is publishing.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0